# Replace value from database with space depending on its length if value is empty/null

Tags: php

Scenario:

```
Database Table 
Column     Type      Length            Sample Values
emp_code   varchar     4            0011      0021    0012
emp_desc   varchar     2            01        03      01
emp_stat   varchar     1            1                 0
```

Problem:

I am querying so that I can write the result into a text file.

```
$file = "data.txt";
$f = fopen($file, "a");
$qry = "SELECT * FROM tbl_emp";
$result = mysqli_query($conn, $qry );
if(!$result) {
    echo "Cannot do query" . "<br/>";
exit;
}

$num_results =mysqli_num_rows($result);
for ($i=0; $i<=$num_results; $i++) {
    $row = mysqli_fetch_assoc ($result);
        $emp_code = (empty($row['emp_code']) ? "    " : $row['emp_code']); //replace with 4 spaces
        $emp_desc = (empty($row['emp_desc']) ? "  " : $row['emp_desc ']);  //replace with 2 spaces
        $emp_stat = (empty($row['emp_code']) ? " " : $row['emp_code']);  //replace with 1 space

     $data = "$emp_code $emp_desc $emp_stat\r\n";
     fwrite($f,$data); 
}
```

Data.Txt should contain:

```
0011011
002103 
0012010
```

But this is the result:

```
0011011
002103 
001201
```

If the value of the row is 0, it replaces it with blank when it shouldn't. What needs to be changed to get the correct data? TIA.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Don't use `empty`. `0` is empty. Depending on what you are checking there it can be one of:

```
$emp_stat = (is_null($row[...]) ? " " : $row[...])
$emp_stat = (($row[...] === "") ? " " : $row[...])
$emp_stat = (is_numeric($row[...])? $row[...] : " ")
```

etc